# Mac OS X. Vi - E185 cannot find color scheme

Tags: macos, vi

Editing with vi in terminal gives the following error.
E185: Cannot find color scheme metacosm. I think the problem is not im my .vimrc (no strange carrage returns). I strongly suspect this problem has to do with os x (10.6).

My .vimrc (line 9).

1. " Favorite Color Scheme
2. if has("gui_running")
3. colorscheme inkpot
4. " Remove Toolbar
5. set guioptions-=T
6. "Terminus is AWESOME
7. set guifont=Terminus\ 9
8. else
9. colorscheme metacosm
10. endif

Comment: Why do you think the problem has something to do with Mac OS X? Where did you put your metacosm colorscheme?

Comment: E185 means that Vim searched your 'runtimepath' for the file colors/metacosm.vim and did not find it. What does the command ":set runtimepath?" show you?

Comment: runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim72,/usr/share/vim
/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colours not found since I had no colors/metacosm.vim. Installing the file in runtimepath solves it.